# Swift TipKit complex rule with filter

Tags: ios, swiftui, tipkit

I'm trying to implement a complex rule to display a Tip from TipKit.

I'm using the official documentation (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/tipkit/tips/event) as example. But the same exact code doesn't compile and gives me the error "The filter function is not supported in this rule." on the line `$0.donations.filter { $0.landmarkName != "Wilbere Bowl" }.count > 3`

```swift
import SwiftUI
import TipKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var tip = InlineTip()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text("Hello, world!")
            TipView(tip)
            Button("TIP") {
                InlineTip.didViewLandmarkDetail.sendDonation(.init(landmarkID: 0, landmarkName: "TEST"))
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct InlineTip: Tip {
    static let didViewLandmarkDetail = Tips.Event<DidViewLandmark>(id: "didViewLandmarkDetail")

    var title: Text {
        Text("Save as a Favorite")
    }

    var message: Text? {
        Text("Your favorite backyards always appear at the top of the list.")
    }

    var image: Image? {
        Image(systemName: "star")
    }

    var rules: [Rule] {
        // Define a rule based on the interaction.
        #Rule(Self.didViewLandmarkDetail) {
            $0.donations.filter { $0.landmarkName != "Wilbere Bowl" }.count > 3
        }
    }
}

struct DidViewLandmark: Codable, Sendable {
    let landmarkID: Int
    let landmarkName: String
}
```

Sorry, if it's a duplicate. I couldn't find anything related to this error.